# Slick.js carousel detect last thumb to load more

Tags: jquery, events, carousel, slick.js

```
$('.carousel').on('afterChange', function(e, slick, cur){
    console.log(slick, cur);
    // if( ?? ) loadMore();
});
```

How can I know if all the slides in the carousel has been seen, so that I can load and append more slides?

If `slidesToShow` was `1`, I'd simply compare the `cur` argument with number of slides, how do I do it when `slidesToShow` & `slidesToScroll` have value of `>1`  and different?

Comment: You could try using `$('.carousel').last()`. Check if that works in `onBeforeChange` or `onAfterChange`

Answer (score 1):

`cur` returns the index (0 based) of the current slide, so you can compare that with the total number of slides - 1. The `slick` object contains a `$slides` object, which is an array representing all of the slides.

With the information above you can detect the last thumb by doing the below:

```
$('.carousel').on('afterChange', function(e, slick, cur) {
  if (cur === slick.$slides.length - 1) {
    //Replace with your "Load More" logic
    console.log('Load More');
  }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/5a2hgys6/)**